# Should I ask for a raise?

Tags: salary, raise

My company was about to hire someone new.  I was asked my thoughts and if I would be willing to take on the responsibilities instead of hiring this person.  I told them that I didn't think they needed to hire a whole new full-time person for the job and that I would be happy to extend my role to contribute what they needed.
Even though I saved the company about 40k/year I was not offered a raise for doing this.  Should I have been?  Should I have asked?  Should I ask in a few weeks after seeing how much my work increases?
Any advice would be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: @joe- I haven't been through an annual cycle yet. I just hit my 3 months. Since they are still getting to know me and my skills I felt that I'm still proving how much I can handle and how much I'm worth to them.

Comment: You definitely should ask for a raise. Regrets born from inactivity are toxic. Be bold.

Answer (score 10):

Firstly, if you saved them $40K in salary, you saved them more than $40K/year.

Secondly, there's a whole different, possibly correct, interpretation here.

What you think you said:

> I'll do more work.  I'll save you money!

What they think you said:

> I've been underworked so far.  I'm overpaid!

For future reference, you should have offered to take on the additional responsibility if they were willing to compensate you, and maybe promote you.  You've lost leverage by waiting, because you can't really back out gracefully.

The save here would be to say that the work was more than anticipated, and that you'll need to increase your hours. You're still willing to do so, but you'd like compensation. If you can perform the work within your normal working hours, you're giving credence to the idea that you were being underutilized before.

If not, you can certainly ask for a raise now. Wait for a major success, so your value if more apparent.

Comment: Maybe I'm being charitable, but I suspect what they heard was "I can make this problem my problem rather than your problem", and they immediately said "OK" and forgot all about that problem. Not their problem anymore.

Comment: @deworde Yes! They probably heard "I can stop thinking about this", and worse--"Next time I think we need to hire, I'm probably wrong".

Answer (score 4):

> Should I have asked? Should I ask in a few weeks after seeing how much my work increases?

Yes you should have asked in the first instance. And yes, you should ask further down the line.

If you're taking on tasks that are outside your original work and they make an impact on your workload and responsibilities, then you should receive more recompense. And most importantly, if you DON'T ask, you'll probably get nothing, so you have nothing to lose by doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Let's simplify this: If you want to make more money, you need to mention it every time there is an opportunity to do so without making you look greedy. The situation you describe was such an opportunity.

If you never bring up the topic, people tend to think you're satisfied with your salary, and might distribute all the money for salary increases amongst the group of people who they don't want to lose and who did ask for a raise.